# How to calculate the rotation at a singularity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields, dirac-delta-distributions

An electrodynamics lecture asks me to prove that
$$
\nabla \times \left( \frac{\vec{M} \times \vec{x}}{ |\vec{x}|^3} \right) = \frac{8 \pi}{3} \vec{M} \delta^3(\vec{x})- \frac{\vec{M}}{|\vec{x}|^3}+ \frac{3\vec{M} \cdot \vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^5}\vec{x}
$$
where $\vec{M}$ is some constant vector.
I have already shown that for $\vec{x} \neq 0$
$$
\nabla \times \left( \frac{\vec{M} \times \vec{x}}{ |\vec{x}|^3} \right) = - \frac{\vec{M}}{|\vec{x}|^3}+ \frac{3\vec{M} \cdot \vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^5}\vec{x}
$$
To determine the value at the singularity I was thinking to consider the integral over any volume V

$$
\int \int \int_V \nabla \times \left( \frac{\vec{M} \times \vec{x}}{ |\vec{x}|^3} \right) d^3x =- \int \int _{dV} \left( \frac{\vec{M} \times \vec{x}}{ |\vec{x}|^3} \right)  \times \vec{da} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
$$
where the equality is due to a special case of the Gaussian theorem. I think I have to show
$$
\int \int \int_V \nabla \times \left( \frac{\vec{M} \times \vec{x}}{ |\vec{x}|^3} \right) d^3x = \frac{8\pi}{3} \vec{M} + \int \int \int_V \left( {- \frac{\vec{M}}{|\vec{x}|^3}+ \frac{3\vec{M} \cdot \vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^5}\vec{x} } \right )d^3x
$$
for all volumes that include the origin.

Is this approach correct? I am stuck at evaluating the integral (*). Can someone give me some pointers? I did not know what this method of integrating singularities by using the delta function is called and I couldn't find anything helpful in my literature or on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Factor before Dirac delta in magnetic dipole field formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/644711/2451)

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a few hints:

The strategy is usually to use a theorem that says that two integrals must be equal.
In your case the classical Gauss' and Stokes' theorems don't seem to work but some hope I see with
$$\tag{1}
\int_V\nabla\times \boldsymbol{F}\,dV=\oint_S\boldsymbol{n}\times \boldsymbol{F}\,dS\,.
$$
For a simple proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732023/how-could-we-define-circulation-over-a-surface-or-a-tangential-surface-integral/4732131#4732131).
Lets take as closed surface $S$ the sphere with radius $r$ around the origin.
Its unit normal is
$$
\boldsymbol{n}=\frac{\boldsymbol{x}}{|\boldsymbol{x}|}\,.
$$
In your case
$$
\boldsymbol{F}=\frac{\boldsymbol{M}\times\boldsymbol{x}}{|\boldsymbol{x}|^3}
$$
and by the Grassmann identity,
$$
\boldsymbol{n}\times\boldsymbol{F}=\frac{\boldsymbol{M}}{|\boldsymbol{x}|^2}-
\frac{(\boldsymbol{M}\cdot\boldsymbol{x})\,\boldsymbol{x}}{|\boldsymbol{x}|^4}\,.
$$
You should now be able to calculate the RHS of (1). I believe it is independent of $|\boldsymbol{x}|=r$ so that in the limit the integrand on the LHS must be a delta function
whose factor can be determined.

Answer (score 0):

By expanding the triple cross product one gets

$$  r>0 :  M \nabla \cdot \frac{\vec{x}} {|\vec{x}|^3} - \frac{\vec{x}} {|\vec{x}|^3}  \nabla \cdot M  = M r^{-2}\partial_r(r^2 * r^{-2}) =0 $$

Per general definition or Gauss theorem, the divergence at $r=0$ is the limit of the radial field components flow integrated over the sphere giving

$$M \nabla \cdot \frac{\vec{x}} {|\vec{x}|^3} = 4 \pi r^2 r^{-2} = 4 \pi $$

independent of r.